# Get reference of interface implementation callback by recyclerview adapter to fragment

Tags: java, android

i'm adding a new item(CardView) in recyclerview in fragment on click of FAB, using interface implementation in RecyclerView's ViewHolder inner class, but unable to get reference of implemented interface in ViewHolder class.

This is for adding new item in recyclerview on click of Floating Action Button.  i've tried parameterised constructor of Fragment for getting reference of implemented interface callback but IDE shows it can't create constructor of fragment.

```
// interface for implementation in viewholder
public interface CallbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView {
    void addNewItem();
}

// fragment class in which need to get reference of viewholder class
public class MultiCitiesFragment extends Fragment {
...
private CallbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView callbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView;


// need to call this method from viewholder class of recyclerview
 public void setOnFABSelectedListener(MultiCitiesRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder multiCitiesRecyclerViewAdapter) {
        callbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView = multiCitiesRecyclerViewAdapter;
    }

// here calling interface method
mFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView.addNewItem();
            }
        });
}

// recyclerview's viewholder class
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener,
            CallbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView {

// calling this method of fragment class from constructor of viewholder
new MultiCitiesFragment().setOnFABSelectedListener(MyViewHolder.this);

// implemented method of interface
@Override
        public void addNewItem() {
            listItem.add(new RecyclerViewItem());
            notifyItemInserted(getAdapterPosition());
            notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), listItem.size());
        }
}
```

I expect the addition of new item in recyclerview, but the output show CallbackInterfaceToAddItemInRecyclerView.addNewItem()' on a null object reference

Comment: your implementation is wrong to add new item in recyclerview, you need to make one method in your adapter and just add item in listitem object using ex:listitem.add(item) and then call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: mean no need to implement interface in viewholder

Comment: how to call that method from fragment's FAB click?